# Include column names in the results of an Oracle SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am typing in SQL queries (`SELECT` ...) in a software tool which is based on an Oracle database.

Now, I would like to have in the first row of the resulting data the names of the columns. Otherwise, on exporting they are not included and I haven't found any option which would allow the latter.

Does anyone have an idea how to include column names in the results of an SQL query?

I understand that there would be some problems if the column has values of type, say, Integer, but then I would probably transform everything simply (how?) to strings.

Comment: If there's an option of exporting to an existing file (as opposed to creating a new one), you could first query the data's meta information (column names, in particular) and write it to a file, then export the data to the same file.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*upon exporting*"? Which tool do you use to export the data? I would search for an option in that tool to include column names.

Comment: Sorry for not being entirely clear. The situation at the moment is that if I do the query, I will get as output a table without the column titles. Then, I can export that output to a csv-file. Unfortunately I haven't found any option in my tool to include the column titles.

Comment: I haven't found an option for exporting to data to an existing file either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a quick and dirty method for doing what you want. If a column was a non-varchar2 type then you'd need to cast the second `SELECT` result to `VARCHAR2`.

See [TO_CHAR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) for the conversion syntax.

```
SELECT 'colname1',
       'colname2',
       'colname3',
       1 AS ordering
  FROM dual
UNION
SELECT colname1,
       colname2,
       colname3,
       2 AS ordering
  FROM yourtable
ORDER BY ordering;
```

If you really don't want to see the "ordering" column then you could wrap the whole statement in another select that just selects the columns you want to see.

I'd have to agree with the comments though, you should ideally be able to export metadata through your IDE tool rather than a workaround.

Hope it helps...