# how to save query results into excel file with column names in mysql

Tags: mysql

i use this query but it not show the column name

> SELECT * FROM employeemaster INTO OUTFILE 'c:/order-1.csv' FIELDS
>   TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include column names in the results of an Oracle SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409845/include-column-names-in-the-results-of-an-oracle-sql-query)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include headers when using SELECT INTO OUTFILE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941809/include-headers-when-using-select-into-outfile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below query:

```
SELECT empid as employeeid,sname as staffname FROM employeemaster INTO
OUTFILE 'c:/order.csv' FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions:

The simple one : hardcode the colum names yourself and join the header line with the query result :

```
SELECT 'Name_I_Want_For_Col1', 'Name_I_Want_For_Col1', 'Name_I_Want_For_Col1'
UNION ALL
SELECT ColName1, ColName2, ColName3
    FROM YourTable
    INTO OUTFILE '/path/outfile'
```

A more straight forward (but more complex one) : 
Get the colum names from information schema :

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("'",COLUMN_NAME,"'"))
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_schema'
order BY ORDINAL_POSITION
UNION ALL
    SELECT ColName1, ColName2, ColName3
        FROM YourTable
        INTO OUTFILE '/path/outfile'
```